# Dual booting Ubuntu18.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, windows-10, brightness

So I recently got myself an Acer Nitro 5 with a Ryzen 7 4800h, and 1650 graphics card. I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 got some ACPI bios errors, got past them but scrolling, screen brightness, keyboard backlit, and various other things weren't working properly.

I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 but the brightness control is still not working, and god knows what else isn't since I haven't tested everything yet. Also I get black screen before logging in and after logging out w some messages and errors flashed for a couple of seconds. In short Ubuntu install isn't clean as well.

What I want?
No. 1) To go back to fresh laptop experience - no ubuntu and disk space allocated back to my windows.
No. 2) As close as possible definitive guide to be followed to install ubuntu successfully and getting everything to work smoothly.

P.S. After installing 20.04 i deleted it's partition from windows disk management tool, and tried expanding my already existing volume as well creating a new one out of it but kept getting error "Not Enough Space Available on The Disk to Extend Volume".

P.P.S. At least 1 will do(please help me get back my machine in its intital state, barely a day old).

TIA

Comment: Many Acer need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. [SOLVED]Acer Nitro 5 (with Ryzen 7 2700U, RX 560X) Ubuntu 18.10  
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412117 &
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/555251/unable-to-install-ubuntu-in-my-nitro-an512-42
Acer Nitro 7 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the GRUB package? Deleting Ubuntu is never a good alternative, but which ever suits you fine is okay.For reference you can check this to see if you have followed this
[https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/remove-partition-windows-10-free.html#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Search%20%22Disk%20Management,system%20complete%20the%20removing%20process](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/remove-partition-windows-10-free.html#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Search%20%22Disk%20Management,system%20complete%20the%20removing%20process).

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Acer, you might need to carry out an extra step :

Follow these steps:

They assume that you are installing Ubuntu, but might also be required for booting from a Live USB

1. Make sure your UEFI is up to date.
2. In UEFI, you must set a supervisor password. Once the supervisor password is set, some new menus are accessible.
3. Enter the "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" menu. It will allow you to declare the newly installed Ubuntu boot image as trusted on your laptop.
4. Select EMMC >> EFI >> Ubuntu and select the file shimx64.efi. You will be prompted to give it a name of your choice (which will appear in the F12 boot options).
5. Type the name press Enter and then "Yes" should be highlighted.
6. Press enter again. Restart the computer without any boot disk and tap F12 during the boot process.
7. You should now get the boot option menu with the name you chose.
8. You can change the boot order in UEFI now so that it boots directly to the Grub screen.
9. Either disable the supervisor password, or save it in a secure place.